# How to add image into v-text-field?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have been trying to add image inside v-text-field, but it is causing an issue when I add it moves label to a bit of right side?

```html
<v-text-field
  ref="phone"
  v-model="phone"
  dense
  outlined
  disabled
  color="black"
  :rule="[requiredRule]"
  :label="$t('10')"
  >
    <template #prepend-inner>
      <v-img style="margin: auto 0" max-height="25" max-width="30" src="/images/KW.png"> </v-img>
    </template>
</v-text-field>
```

[image]

as you can see label PHONE moves to right side it isn't staying on its place, I tried to add margin-top but didn't fix it.

Comment: v-text-field doesn't seem to support images, you can only add icons https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#icons

Another option would be to inspect in your browser what html elements the component expands to and use the basic html from that then add your image inside

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.

I looked for it in html while inspecting but couldn't find the proper solution.

Comment: But now the weird thing is, on smaller displays it works just fine, but on displays over 1080p it behaves like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an undocumented feature, which explains why the behaviour may be unexpected.

The cause of the seems to me is that the input calculates the width of the slot content at the time of rendering, which due to a race condition may resolve before or after the image is rendered. That's why if you render multiple times, you may not always see it behaving this way.

To get around it, I thing you should be able to wrap the image with another element of fixed width. (`<div style="width:30px">`)

```html
<v-text-field
  ref="phone"
  v-model="phone"
  dense
  outlined
  label="My Label"
>
  <template #prepend-inner>
    <div style="width:30px">
      <v-img style="margin: auto 0" max-height="25" max-width="30" src="/images/KW.png"/>
    </div>
  </template>
</v-text-field>
```

Comment: Thank You, This thing fixed the issue but I still don't properly understand what was causing the issue :(

Comment: I believe it's [this bit](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/ff519c6121cc995069caba9b232c216633d6f801/packages/vuetify/src/components/VTextField/VTextField.ts#L521) it sometimes uses the `offsetWidth` **before** and sometimes **after** the image is loaded. So if the image is not loaded yet the number is off, but if you do a resize, the recalculation is triggered and the location is fixed. That is why it works with a fixed size.